# Keyboard mapping on ChromeOS?

Tags: keyboard-layout, chrome-book, chrome-os

The down arrow key on my Chromebook is broken. I have been trying to find a way to map the arrow keys to the WASD keys. I have found that this cannot be accomplished through ChromeOS itself, and all of the apps and extensions that I have looked at in the Chrome Web Store do not quite seem to accomplish this either. Does anybody know of some way to map/substitute keys on ChromeOS?

Thank you!